# at least one passenger in each station

Tags: probability

I have the following problem:
There is a bus with $30$ passengers that are going to get off at the next $3$ stations $S_1,S_2,S_3$.Find the probability that at least one passenger gets off the bus at each of the stations.I tried to find the probability of the complement event but didn't manage to complete the calculation.Any ideas?

Comment: try inclusion exclusion.  What's the probability that one specified stop is skipped?  What's the probability that two specified stops are skipped?

Comment: As a technical point, you should specify that each passenger gets off at a stop uniformly at random and independent of all the other passengers (assuming that is what you intend, of course).

Comment: Also:  are you sure you've stated the problem correctly and completely?  If everyone gets off randomly and independently the probability that a stop is skipped is quite small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its random (which seems stupid), then you can use [Sterling numbers of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheSecondKind.html) to count all the ways in which the people could get off.

$S(30,1) = 1$

$S(30,2) = 536,870,911$

$S(30,3) = 34,314,651,811,530$

There are $\binom{3}{1}$ ways to get off at 1 stop, and $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to get off at 2 stops, so we have to multiply $S(30,1)$ and $S(30,2)$ by 3. Additionally There are $3!$ ways to order each of the outcomes of $S(30,3)$ and $2!$ to order $S(30,2)$.

So then we have the probability someone gets off at each station as

$\cfrac{3! \cdot S(30,3)}{3! S(30,3) + 2! \binom{3}{2 }S(30,2) + \binom{3}{1}S(30,1)}$

$\cfrac{205887910869180}{ 205887910869180 + 3221225466 + 3} = 999984354714862$

Comment: This doesn't look right.  Are your events all equiprobable?  The probability of missing one specified stop is $\left(\frac 23 \right)^{30}$.  The probability of missing two specified stops is $\left(\frac 13 \right)^{30}$.  Thus the answer is $1-3\times \left(\frac 23 \right)^{30}+3\times \left(\frac 13 \right)^{30}=0.999968709$

Comment: @lulu I see my error, I need to multiple $S(30,1)$ and $S(30,2)$ by 3, to account for the ways in which they could get off on 1 or 2 stops...I always fdorget to do that :(

Comment: @lulu I still get a different asnwer (I also get a different answer than you when I do your calculation). Im not sure what the difference would be, This should be the total number of ways 30 people can get off on any combination of 3 stops, and all are equally likely

Comment: Yes, I first ran the calculation on an inadequate platform.  On a better platform I get $0.99998435471486\dots$.  I still don't think your events are equiprobable, however.  It's hard to tell with these numbers as the probability of skipping a stop is obviously negligible.

Comment: @lulu hmmm, thats what I got when I originally did it without multiplying $S(30,1)$ and $S(30,2)$ by three.

Comment: Now I am confused.  I have changed my mind...your events are equiprobable and your method ought to work perfectly.  I just repeated your calculation from scratch and got the same value you got.

Comment: I think I, for one, need to review exactly what the Sterling numbers count.  Anyway, ($+1$) for your idea which is fundamentally different, I think, from the method I proposed.

Comment: As an example:  say we had $3$ distinguishable people instead of $30$.  Then there are $6$ ways to use all the stops and $3^3=27$ ways for them to get off the bus.  Thus the answer is $\frac 6{27}=\frac 29$.  My method gives $1-3\times \left( \frac 23 \right)^3 +3\times \left( \frac 13 \right)^3=\frac 29$.  So, good.  At the same time, $S[3,3]=1,S[3,2]=3,S[3,1]=1$ and it simply isn't true that $\frac {S[3,3]}{S[3,3]+S[3,2]+S[3,1]}=\frac 29$.  Nor that $\frac {S[3,3]}{S[3,3]+3\times S[3,2]+3\times S[3,1]}=\frac 29$.

Comment: Also, as bizarre as it sounds, our answers do not actually match.  My method gives $0.99998435471486203111745980\dots$ where yours, absent the factors of $3$, gives $0.99998435471484746053817537981743\dots$.  They are, of course, absurdly close.

Comment: @lulu, nice work. I figured how to make the sterling numbers work. $S(3,3)$ can be permutated 3 ways, $S(3,2)$ can be permuated 2 ways. So in addition to multiplying them by the ways in which could account for stops, they need to be permutated to account for the order they could have gotten off at those chosen stops. An awful lot of work, when your solution is much simpler. Lol. At least I know whats wrong now, it was bugging the hell out of me